# Get all row data in one field

Tags: php, mysql

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT c.id, c.name FROM (SELECT @r AS _id, (SELECT @r := parent FROM categories WHERE id = _id) AS parent, @l := @l + 1 AS lvl FROM (SELECT @r := 74, @l := 0) vars, categories m WHERE @r <> 0) m JOIN categories c ON m._id = c.id ORDER BY m.lvl DESC;");           
                    while($bread = $stmt->fetch()){                         
                        $plip = $bread['name'];
                        $each = "$plip-";
                        echo $each;
                        echo "<label value='$each'></label>";                                   

                    }
```

`echo $each` is given this output: "Milk-Cat-Cookie" and that was what I want, so its good.

but echo `<label value='$each'></label>` is given this output: `<label value='Milk-'></label>`

but it must be like that : `<label value='Milk-Cat-Cookie'></label>`

So why I can't show all row data in one field?

Comment: `echo "<label value='".$each."'></label>";`

Comment: try `<label value=".$each."></label>` , although i think labels cannot have value, if u want text inside the label, do `<label>'$each'</label>`

Comment: no, all this solutions give me same thing. I dont want to loop rows. query given this result milk-cat-cookie each of them is a row. But I want all these rows in one field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT c.id, c.name FROM (SELECT @r AS _id, (SELECT @r := parent FROM categories WHERE id = _id) AS parent, @l := @l + 1 AS lvl FROM (SELECT @r := 74, @l := 0) vars, categories m WHERE @r <> 0) m JOIN categories c ON m._id = c.id ORDER BY m.lvl DESC;");           
                    while($bread = $stmt->fetch()){                         
                        $plip = $bread['name'];
                        $each = "$plip-";
                        echo $each;
                        echo "<label value='$each'></label>";                                   

                    }
```

Should be:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT c.id, c.name FROM (SELECT @r AS _id, (SELECT @r := parent FROM categories WHERE id = _id) AS parent, @l := @l + 1 AS lvl FROM (SELECT @r := 74, @l := 0) vars, categories m WHERE @r <> 0) m JOIN categories c ON m._id = c.id ORDER BY m.lvl DESC;");           
                    echo "<label value='";
                     $each='';
           while($bread = $stmt->fetch()){                         
                        $plip = $bread['name'];
                        $each .= "$plip-";


                }
                 echo $each;  
             echo "'></label>";
```

I left only variable echo inside the loop. Btw with your code you should trim last - or is ok to leave it?

Comment: You are welcome. Then mark the answer as solved please

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the echo `<label value='$each'></label>;` line out of the "while" sintax, something like this:

```
while($bread = $stmt->fetch()){                         
    $plip = $bread['name'];
    $each = "$plip-";
    echo $each;
}
echo "<label value='$each'></label>";
```

Be aware that I concat on every iteration on the result on `$each` variable.